# How to utilize python in command terminal with remote files

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, hpc, box

I have used command terminal to connect to my institution's HPC shared cluster and then accessed an online file storage system, Box, that contains both my python script and the files that the script uses. I want to run the python script but get the error message "Unknown Commmand 'python'." I added python to the path of my computer in environmental variables but I think that the way I have everything set, the HPC cluster is considered my local files and the online file storage is considered my remote files. Therefore, adding python to the path on my computer does not add it to the local or remote systems I have open.

I hope I have explained this clearly. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Without additional details, it is difficult to answer this question. Do you have Python installed on your HPC?

Comment: Yes. Python works on the HPC but once I access box, I can't seem to run Python. I think my actual question may be how to transfer the files from Box to the HPC to run the script and then how to move everything back to Box.

Comment: If you have SSH access to your HPC you can transfer the files from your computer to there. Again, without knowing more about your particular setup, it is rather difficult to help you. It is also off-topic for this site I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal you can run Python files by simply running:

```
python /your/file/path/file_name.py
```

If you want to run it explicitly with python3 you can use:

```
python3 /your/file/path/file_name.py
```

You can check which python will run by default by running this command in your terminal:

```
python --version
```

Hope this helps!